# Cannot create a pandas Dataframe from 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
python 3.5.2
numpy 1.11.1
```

I'm having problems creating a `dataframe` from a `2-dimensional list` created from splitting up a text file. Here's a sample of the text file:

```
   #freq [MHz]   #flags    #total   %flagged\n947.6 1451736.0 1451736.0
1.0\n947.615625 1451736.0 1451736.0 1.0\n947.63125  1451736.0 1451736.0
1.0\n947.646875 1451736.0 1451736.0 1.0\n947.6625   1451736.0 1451736.0 
1.0\n947.678125 1451736.0 1451736.0 1.0\n947.69375  1451736.0 1451736.0 
1.0\n947.709375 1451736.0 1451736.0 1.0\n947.725    1451736.0 1451736.0 
1.0\n947.740625 1451736.0 1451736.0 1.0\n947.75625  1451736.0 1451736.0 
1.0\n947.771875 1451736.0 1451736.0 1.0\n947.7875   1451736.0 1451736.0 
1.0\n947.803125 1451736.0 1451736.0 1.0\n947.8 ....
```

So the lines are separated by `\n`, and each column is separated by a `space`. I parse this out with:

```
obs_array = []
obs_1 = obs_txts[obs].split('\n')
for i in range(0,len(obs_1)):
    obs_array.append(obs_1[i].split(' '))
```

So I get `obs_array` as a 2 dimensional list. I get rid of the `first row` (just column names, I'll rename once I have a working `dataframe`) and the `last row`, which is just an empty `''`. So, I now have a 2 dimensional list that has `30720 rows`and `4 columns`. I can turn this into an array:

```
obs_array = np.array(obs_array)
```

but the shape of this array returns (30720,). I checked the length of every row, each one returns 4 and trying to force the shape to be (30720,4) returns a `size error`. I know for sure that there should be 30720 rows. Putting this into a `dataframe`

```
obs_df = pd.DataFrame(obsarray)
```

returns

```
0

0   [947.6, 1451736.0, 1451736.0, 1.0]

1   [947.615625, 1451736.0, 1451736.0, 1.0]

2   [947.63125, 1451736.0, 1451736.0, 1.0]

3   [947.646875, 1451736.0, 1451736.0, 1.0]

4   [947.6625, 1451736.0, 1451736.0, 1.0]
```

In other words, a `30720x1 dimensioned dataframe` where each row has one entry: a list of that row.

What is going on here? Why can't I get python to interpret obs_array with a shape of `(30720,4)`? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I am really confused as to why you could not just use `pd.read_table` to import the file? In any case, try `obs_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(obs_array)`.

Comment: Was not aware of pd.read_table. This worked, albeit a bit roughly since it interprets the first row as having 6 elements, but that is easy to fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So after `obs_array = np.array(obs_array)` you can run `pd.DataFrame(obs_array.tolist())` which will give you the following dataframe:

```
        0       1            2         3     4      5
  0     #       freq        [MHz]    #flags #total  %flagged
  1 947.6       1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  2 947.615625  1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  3 947.63125   1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  4 947.646875  1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  5 947.6625    1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  6 947.678125  1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  7 947.69375   1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  8 947.709375  1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
  9 947.725     1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
 10 947.740625  1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
 11 947.75625   1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
 12 947.771875  1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
 13 947.7875    1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
 14 947.803125  1451736.0   1451736.0   1.0 None    None
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.